# Angular factory, object scope confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm trying to modify a variable inside a function, but there must be something with the scope that I'm not understanding, code:

```
app.factory("UserService", function(){
var foo = 'bar';
return {
    init: function(){
        var self = this;
        self.create();
    },
    create: function(){
        $.post(server+"api/users", { 
                uuid: self.uuid 
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                if(data.reply !== 0){ 
                    foo = true;
                } else {
                    foo = false;
                }

            });
            return foo;                
        }
    };
});
```

Why can't I change the value of foo from within the functions? I've tried doing this.foo, self.foo, after assigning this to self, among so many other things, and I believe I'm missing something way too obvious and I'll feel like an idiot after someone clears it up for me.

Thanks.

Comment: You can. What you *can't* do is pretend $.post isn't async and try to *return* it from an async function.

Comment: How do I get around that? I need to know if the create() function gets executed properly or not, can I simply change foo inside the function and later down the line check the value of foo, without returning anything?

Comment: You have to return a promise. The issue isn't about scope or context.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code you need to first change `$.post` to `$http.post` to get better controller over binding by executing $digest cycle after its execution,
Using jQuery inside angular would create more problem with scope `digest` cycle.

Your code will not work because you made an Ajax from the code and returning variable from outside of done, It should be return from the completion of promise using `done` or success method.

**Service**

```
app.factory("UserService", function($http) {
    var foo = 'bar';
    return {
        init: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.create();
        },
        create: function() {
            return $http.post(server + "api/users", {
                    uuid: self.uuid
                })
                .then(function(res) {
                    if (res.data.reply !== 0) {
                        return foo = true; //returning data when promise is resolved
                    } else {
                        return foo = false; //returning data when promise is resolved
                    }

                });
        }
    };
});
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: if I assign the function to a variable, eg; r = self.create(); and then console.log(r); I get [object Object]

Comment: if you want to get result then from `create()` do `self.create().then(function(data){ console.log(data);//here you will get value of foo inside data})` ..Use then to resolve chain promise because create method return a promise object..

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in my own factory code, and noticed that the OP never signed off on this post. Why is that ?

Comment: Yes indeed, but through another post that someone assisted with - i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406163/angular-issue-with-asynchronous-call-to-function/32406468?noredirect=1#comment52685620_32406468

Comment: @PankajParkar - please see my new post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461842/scope-issues-in-my-angular-factory-code . I would appreciate your feedback - greatly !

Comment: @PankajParkar - thank you anyway for taking the time to response.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
app.factory("UserService", function(){
var foo = 'bar';
return {
    init: function(){
        var self = this;
        self.create();
    },
    create: function(){
        $.post(server+"api/users", { 
                uuid: self.uuid 
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                if(data.reply !== 0){ 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            });

        }
    };
});
```

This should return true or false when the asynchronus function is done.

Cheers,

Valentin

Comment: Wouldn't the function that called `create` be long-done by then?