# Scope issues in my Angular factory code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an Angular factory called `'DashboardState'`, which I am currently modifying to handle an API call via my `dashboardcontext` Angular service layer.

Currently all my `widget` data is persisted to the `localStorage` object; however, I am now hooking into a new c# API layer which sets/gets the layout widgets to/from permanent storage (i.e. Sql Server database in this case).

My primary issue is what happens when the `promise` is returned at `return this._getItemFromAPI($rootScope).then` of the `load:` function.

In the `load:` section, `this` is a valid object with methods on the stack; however, within the `.then` section I suddenly lose access to `this.`.

It's a problem for me because I can no longer call `this._handleSyncLoad`. And as you can see, I've tried a hack by assigning `var handleSync = this._handleSyncLoad;`, however it doesn't solve the scope issue.:

```
  if (dashboardId != null && dashboardId != undefined) {

                  this.storage.setItem("defaultDashboardId", dashboardId);

                  var handleSync = this._handleSyncLoad;
                  return this._getItemFromAPI($rootScope).then(function (data) {                           
                      // save current current dashboard id for next time - 06/11/2015 BM:      

                      return handleSync(data, true);    

                   });                      
              }
```

Here's the full listing of `'DashboardState'` :

```js
angular.module('ui.dashboard')
.factory('DashboardState', ['$log', '$q', 'dashboardcontext', '$rootScope', function ($log, $q, dashboardcontext, $rootScope) {
function DashboardState(storage, id, hash, widgetDefinitions, stringify) {
  this.storage = storage;
  this.id = id;
  this.hash = hash;
  this.widgetDefinitions = widgetDefinitions;
  this.stringify = stringify;
}

DashboardState.prototype = {
  /**
   * Takes array of widget instance objects, serializes, and saves state.
   * 
   * @param  {Array} widgets  scope.widgets from dashboard directive
   * @return {Boolean}        true on success, false on failure
   */
 save: function (widgets) {             
      // CODE OMITTED FOR SAVE FUNCTION
      return true;
  },                   
 load: function (dashboardId) {        // sent in from navigation-controller call 

      var useLocalStorage = false;     // retrieve from localStorage or via API layer

      var serialized;

      if (useLocalStorage) {           // retrieve dashboard layout from localStorage                  
       // COME CODE OMITTED FOR BREVITY
       serialized = this.storage.getItem(dashboardId);                  
   }
      }
      else {                  

   // FETCH DASHBOARD HERE !! 
   if (dashboardId != null && dashboardId != undefined) {

       // *** "this" is available on the scope at this point ***
       this.storage.setItem("defaultDashboardId", dashboardId);

       var handleSync = this._handleSyncLoad;
       return this._getItemFromAPI($rootScope).then(function (data) {                                                         
    // *** "this" IS NO LONGER AVAILABLE ON THE SCOPE - i.e. I can no longer call this._handleSyncLoad from here ***
    return handleSync(data, true);    

        });                      
   }
   else {
       // revert to original line; see dashboardOptions to main-controller
       serialized = this.storage.getItem(this.id);
   }                  
      }

      if (serialized) {
   // check for promise
   if (angular.isObject(serialized)) {    // && angular.isFunction(serialized.then)) {    // modifed line 09/04/2015 BM:
       return this._handleAsyncLoad(serialized);
   }
   // otherwise handle synchronous load
   return this._handleSyncLoad(serialized);
      } else {
   return null;
      }

  },         

  _getItemFromAPI: function ($rootscope) {
      // SERVER-SIDE API CALL TO PERSIST DASHBOARD TO STORAGE - 09/03/2015 BM:
      var sid = $rootScope.rageSessionVars.sessionID;
      var userid = $rootScope.rageSessionVars.userID;
      var dashboardId = this.id;

      return dashboardcontext.getDashboardImage(sid, userid, dashboardId).then(function (data) {
   if (data.status == "FAIL") {
       window.alert("Failed to retrieve dashboard. " + data.messages);
       return false;
   }
   else {                      
       return data;
   }
      });            
  },

  _handleSyncLoad: function (serialized, isParsed) {


      // **** MUST HANDLE THE isParsed PARAM; serialized object is alredy parsed ****

      var deserialized, result = [];

      if (!serialized) {
   return null;
      }

      if (this == undefined) {    // problem if coming from .then of this._getItemFromAPI in load:  - 09/04/2015 BM:

   deserialized = JSON.parse(serialized);

      }
      else {
   if (this.stringify) {
       try { // to deserialize the string

    deserialized = JSON.parse(serialized);

       } catch (e) {

    // bad JSON, log a warning and return
    $log.warn('Serialized dashboard state was malformed and could not be parsed: ', serialized);
    return null;

       }
   }
   else {
       deserialized = serialized;
   }
      }

      // check hash against current hash
      if (deserialized.hash !== this.hash) {

   $log.info('Serialized dashboard from storage was stale (old hash: ' + deserialized.hash + ', new hash: ' + this.hash + ')');
   this.storage.removeItem(this.id);
   return null;

      }

      // Cache widgets
      var savedWidgetDefs = deserialized.widgets;

      // instantiate widgets from stored data
      for (var i = 0; i < savedWidgetDefs.length; i++) {

   // deserialized object
   var savedWidgetDef = savedWidgetDefs[i];

   // widget definition to use
   var widgetDefinition = this.widgetDefinitions.getByName(savedWidgetDef.name);

   // check for no widget
   if (!widgetDefinition) {
       // no widget definition found, remove and return false
       $log.warn('Widget with name "' + savedWidgetDef.name + '" was not found in given widget definition objects');
       continue;
   }

   // check widget-specific storageHash
   if (widgetDefinition.hasOwnProperty('storageHash') && widgetDefinition.storageHash !== savedWidgetDef.storageHash) {
       // widget definition was found, but storageHash was stale, removing storage
       $log.info('Widget Definition Object with name "' + savedWidgetDef.name + '" was found ' +
  'but the storageHash property on the widget definition is different from that on the ' +
  'serialized widget loaded from storage. hash from storage: "' + savedWidgetDef.storageHash + '"' +
  ', hash from WDO: "' + widgetDefinition.storageHash + '"');
       continue;
   }

   // push instantiated widget to result array
   result.push(savedWidgetDef);
      }

      return result;
  },

  _handleAsyncLoad: function (promise) {
      var self = this;
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      promise.then(
 // success
 function (res) {
     var result = self._handleSyncLoad(res);
     if (result) {
  deferred.resolve(result);
     } else {
  deferred.reject(result);
     }
 },
 // failure
 function (res) {
     deferred.reject(res);
 }
      );

      return deferred.promise;
  }

};

return DashboardState;
}]);
```

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

regards,
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` always refers to the current function so if you nest function definitions you have to work around it somehow.

This is a typical pattern that should solve your issue:

```
function someFunction() {
  var that = this;
  doSomething().then(function() {
    // 'that' is your 'this'
  });
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think you're onto something here. I assigned `that = this` above the constructor `function DashboardState(storage, id, hash, widgetDefinitions, stringify)` - and `that` now contains the valid object.

Comment: Yes, it worked. The key was to add `var that = this;` at the top of my factory code; but, OUTSIDE my constructor. Then reassigned `that = this;` inside the `load:` function.